# Adding hidden component to jspdf

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jspdf, html2canvas

I'm trying to **add a hidden div to my jspdf file**.  I'm currently using **html2canvas** to **add it to the pdf**.

However I currently have to make the div **visible then add it to the pdf then make it not visible**.

I don't like this method because it shows up very briefly on the screen.

I'd prefer if I could just use the **hidden attribute**, but when I try this I get a Supplied

> Data is not a valid base64-String error.

Is there a way to add a fix there error in `typescript/react`?

Or is there a way for me to add a **visibity: hidden div to the pdf**?  When I try to add a `visibility: hidden` div now nothing shows up.

```
const input = document.getElementById('someDiv');
html2canvas(input)
   .then((canvas) => {
      const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      const pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'in', 'a4');
      pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', .25, .25);
      pdf.save('download.pdf');
});
```

```
 <div id='someDiv'>
    ...stuff....
 </div>
```

```
#someDiv{
visibility: hidden;
   float: right;
   height:0;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Have you solved this problem ?

Comment: I did a work around.  What i did was changed the visibilty before and after the jspdf.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `display: none`, it will remove the element out of document

```css
#someDiv {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: When i try that i get the same `Supplied Data is not a valid base64-String jsPDF.convertStringToImageData` error. @ThanhPhan